# MS Access DB to azure

Tags: nosql, azure-sql-database, ms-access-2010

I know we can migrate ms access database to ms sql and then migrate to azure sql.  Is there any other option to migrate MS Access database to NoSQL database in azure (like azure tables) or any cheaper database in azure ?
Please help.

Comment: Azure SQL Database - DTU Model - Basic tier is just 5 dollars a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other option to migrate MS Access database to NoSQL
>   database in azure (like azure tables)

Surely,please get an idea of [Azure Data Factory copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) which could transfer your data from [Access DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-microsoft-access) to other destinations:including azure SQL DB,[azure table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage) etc.

Please follow above tutorial to configure Access DB as source dataset and Table Storage as sink dataset in the copy activity, then execute it in the pipeline.

From a cost point of view,azure storage is relatively cheap for no sql storage.Please see the [price](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/tables/) details of it.

Comment: Does an azure datafactory's copyactivity , while copying the data from MS Access to Azure table , does it also migrate it ?

Comment: @MSTechnie nono...just copy, not migrate.

Comment: @MSTechnie Hi,if my answer is helpful,would you please accept it answer for others' reference on the forum,thx.

Comment: So will the data from msaccess be compatible to azure table ,by just copy activity...is no transformation required ?